# How to get the defaultValue as input using onChange with React Axios, Express, MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

I'm making a CRUD project for my academics using Node, Express, MySQL, and React.
However, I'm stuck in my updating part. How do I pass a defaultValue without changing it and pass it to onChange and every onChange on the form will be submitted to my Axios.put()?
Here are my codes:
My app.put() in my index.js in my server or node express folder:

```
app.put('/employeelistupdate', (req,res) => {
 const employeeid = req.body.employeeid
 const newemployeelastname = req.body.newemployeelastname
 const newemployeefirstname = req.body.newemployeefirstname
 const newemployeemiddlename = req.body.newemployeemiddlename
 const newemployeeblock = req.body.enewmployeeblock
 const newemployeelot = req.body.newemployeelot
 const newemployeestreet = req.body.newemployeestreet
 const newemployeevillage = req.body.newemployeevillage
 const newemployeebarangay = req.body.newemployeebarangay
 const newemployeecity = req.body.newemployeecity
 const newemployeeprovince = req.body.newemployeeprovince
 const newemployeezipcode = req.body.newemployeezipcode
 const newemployeecontact1 = req.body.newemployeecontact1
 const newemployeecontact2 = req.body.newemployeecontact2
 const newemployeecontact3 = req.body.newemployeecontact3
 const newemployeecontact4 = req.body.newemployeeconewntact4
 const newemployeeeducationalattainment = req.body.employeeeducationalattainment
 const newemployeeposition = req.body.newemployeeposition
 const newemployeestatus= req.body.newemployeestatus
 const newsqlemployeeupdate = "UPDATE employeeprofile SET employeelastname = ?, employeefirstname = ?, employeemiddlename = ?, employeeblock = ?, employeelot = ?, employeestreet = ?, employeevillage = ?, employeebarangay = ?, employeecity = ?, employeeprovince = ?, employeezipcode = ?, employeecontact1 = ?, employeecontact2 = ?, employeecontact3 = ?, employeecontact4 = ?, employeeeducationalattainment = ?, employeeposition = ?, employeestatus = ? WHERE employeeid = ?";
 db.query(sqlemployeeupdate, [employeeid, newemployeelastname, newemployeefirstname, newemployeemiddlename, newemployeeblock, newemployeelot, newemployeestreet, newemployeevillage, newemployeebarangay, newemployeecity, newemployeeprovince, newemployeezipcode, newemployeecontact1, newemployeecontact2, newemployeecontact3, newemployeecontact4, newemployeeeducationalattainment, newemployeeposition, newemployeestatus], (err, result) => {
 if (err) console.log(err);
    });
})
```

And here's my edit form in my Employeelistedit.js in my client or react folder:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

function Employeelistedit() {
 const { employeeid } = useParams();
 const x = employeeid
 console.log(x)
 const [employeeinfo, setemployeeinfo] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() =>{
 Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/employeelistedit/${x}`).then((response) => {
 setemployeeinfo(response.data);
    })
  }, [x])
 console.log(employeeinfo)
 useEffect(() =>{
 Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/employeelist').then((response) => {
 setemployeelist(response.data);
    })
  }, [])
 
 const [newemployeelastname, setnewemployeelastname] = useState("");
 const [newemployeefirstname, setnewemployeefirstname] = useState("");
 const [newemployeemiddlename, setnewemployeemiddlename] = useState("");
 const [newemployeeblock, setnewemployeeblock] = useState("");
 const [newemployeelot, setnewemployeelot] = useState("");
 const [newemployeestreet, setnewemployeestreet] = useState("");
 const [newemployeevillage, setnewemployeevillage] = useState("");
 const [newemployeebarangay, setnewemployeebarangay] = useState("");
 const [newemployeecity, setnewemployeecity] = useState("");
 const [newemployeeprovince, setnewemployeeprovince] = useState("");
 const [newemployeezipcode, setnewemployeezipcode] = useState("");
 const [newemployeecontact1, setnewemployeecontact1] = useState("");
 const [newemployeecontact2, setnewemployeecontact2] = useState("");
 const [newemployeecontact3, setnewemployeecontact3] = useState("");
 const [newemployeecontact4, setnewemployeecontact4] = useState("");
 const [newemployeeeducationalattainment, setnewemployeeeducationalattainment] = useState("");
 const [newemployeeposition, setnewemployeeposition] = useState("");
 const [newemployeestatus, setnewemployeestatus] = useState("");
 const [newemployeelist, setnewemployeelist] = useState([]);
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 const register = (employeeid) => {
 var a = document.forms["myform"]["ainput"].value;
 var b = document.forms["myform"]["binput"].value;
 var c = document.forms["myform"]["cinput"].value;
 var d = document.forms["myform"]["dinput"].value;
 var e = document.forms["myform"]["einput"].value;
 var f = document.forms["myform"]["finput"].value;
 var g = document.forms["myform"]["ginput"].value;
 var h = document.forms["myform"]["hinput"].value;
 var i = document.forms["myform"]["iinput"].value;
 var j = document.forms["myform"]["jinput"].value;
 var k = document.forms["myform"]["kinput"].value;
 var l = document.forms["myform"]["linput"].value;
 if (a == "" ||b == "" ||c == "" ||d == "" ||e == "" ||f == "" ||g == "" ||h == "" ||i == "" ||j == "" ||k == "" ||l == "") {
 alert("Required fields must be filled out");
    }
 else {
 Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/employeelistupdate", {employeeid: employeeid, newemployeelastname: newemployeelastname, newemployeefirstname: newemployeefirstname, newemployeemiddlename: newemployeemiddlename, newemployeeblock: newemployeeblock, newemployeelot: newemployeelot, newemployeestreet: newemployeestreet, newemployeevillage: newemployeevillage, newemployeebarangay: newemployeebarangay, newemployeecity: newemployeecity, newemployeeprovince: newemployeeprovince, newemployeezipcode: newemployeezipcode, newemployeecontact1: newemployeecontact1, newemployeecontact2: newemployeecontact2, newemployeecontact3: newemployeecontact3, newemployeecontact4: newemployeecontact4, newemployeeeducationalattainment: newemployeeeducationalattainment, newemployeeposition: newemployeeposition, newemployeestatus: newemployeestatus});
 setnewemployeelist("");
 console.log("Employee Lastname:", newemployeelastname)
 console.log("ID:", employeeid)
 
    }
  }
 return (
 <div className='App'>
 {employeeinfo.map((val) => {
 return (
 <div>
 <div class="headform">
 <h1 class="titleheadform">{val.employeelastname}, {val.employeefirstname}'s Account Edit</h1>
 </div>
 <main class="container-fluid">
 <Link to="/employeelist"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark backbutton">Back</button></Link>
 <form class="formdiv" name="myform" required>
 <h6><i>labels with asterisk (*) are required to be filled out</i></h6>
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault"><h3>Employee Name</h3></label>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Last Name *</label>
 <input name="ainput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeelastname} defaultValue={val.employeelastname} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeelastname(e.target.value)}} required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">First Name *</label>
 <input name="binput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeefirstname} defaultValue={val.employeefirstname} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeefirstname(e.target.value)}} required/>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Middle Name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeemiddlename} defaultValue={val.employeemiddlename} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeemiddlename(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault"><h3>Address</h3></label>
 <div class="form-group">
 
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Block *</label>
 <input name="cinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeeblock} defaultValue={val.employeeblock} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeeblock(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Lot *</label>
 <input name="dinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeelot} defaultValue={val.employeelot} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeelot(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Street</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeestreet} defaultValue={val.employeestreet} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeestreet(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Village *</label>
 <input name="einput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeevillage} defaultValue={val.employeevillage} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeevillage(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Barangay *</label>
 <input name="finput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeebarangay} defaultValue={val.employeebarangay} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeebarangay(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">City *</label>
 <input name="ginput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeecity} defaultValue={val.employeecity} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeecity(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Province *</label>
 <input name="hinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeeprovince} defaultValue={val.employeeprovince} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeeprovince(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Zip Code</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeezipcode} defaultValue={val.employeezipcode} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeezipcode(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Contact Number #1 *</label>
 <input name="iinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeecontact1} defaultValue={val.employeecontact1} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeecontact1(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Contact Number #2</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeecontact2} defaultValue={val.employeecontact2} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeecontact2(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Contact Number #3</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeecontact3} defaultValue={val.employeecontact3} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeecontact3(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Contact Number #4</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeecontact4} defaultValue={val.employeecontact3} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeecontact4(e.target.value)}} />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Educational Attainment *</label>
 <input name="jinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeeeducationalattainment} defaultValue={val.employeeeducationalattainment} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeeeducationalattainment(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-form-label mt-4" for="inputDefault">Position *</label>
 <input name="kinput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={val.employeeposition} defaultValue={val.employeeposition} id="inputDefault" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeeposition(e.target.value)}} required />
 </div>
 <fieldset class="form-group" name="linput" onChange={(e) =>{setnewemployeestatus(e.target.value)}} required>
 <legend class="mt-4">Status *</legend>
 <div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="Full Time" defaultChecked={val.employeestatus === 'Full Time'} />
 <label class="form-check-label" for="optionsRadios1">
                    Full Time
 </label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="Part Time" defaultChecked={val.employeestatus === 'Part Time'} />
 <label class="form-check-label" for="optionsRadios2">
                    Part Time
 </label>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-4">Job Description</label>
 
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-4">ID Picture *</label>
 
 </div>
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success submitbutton" onClick={() => {register(employeeid)}}>Submit</button>
 
 </form>
 </main>
 </div>
            )
        })} 
 </div>
  );
}

export default Employeelistedit;
```

I'm sorry if the codes are long. The declarations and input have many lines. If I'm about to edit one input field, the other input fields with defaultValue shown will pass a blank input.

Then I would see these errors in my console:

```
PUT http://localhost:3001/employeelistupdate 500 (Internal Server Error)
:3000/employeelistedit/1:1 
Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Any help from someone would be really much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should really use some library like `react-hook-form` it would reduce the size of your code.

Comment: There should be some additional information in the backend console about the error.

Comment: I'll study about react-hook-form to have clean codes next time.

Comment: In what way can i get those additional information maam/sir?

Comment: Error 500 means that something went wrong on the server. You are probably getting an error in the terminal where you started your server

Comment: I solved the Error 500 with your guide, thank you, but the main problem is still there. I can't still get the defaultValue as the value that is needed to be passed to onChange. the onChange will only receive a blank input if i won't edit the input field with the defaultValue as the input (since i dont intend to edit its value,leaving it as it is) when submitting it.